# Render a React Form using a list of properties

Tags: reactjs

First of all, I want to say that I am still scratching the surface with React, so apologise if this question seems dumb and obvious.

I want to make a contact form with some fields and I want to render my interface using that fields. Just like this:

Name
[____________]

Email
[____________]

Password
[___________]

etc...

My react code (index.jsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { logger } from './middleware';
import styles from './main.css';

var BillingLabel = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<b>First Name</b>);
  }
});

var BillingInput = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="First name"
            />
        </form>
    );
  }
});

var BillingOption = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <BillingLabel/>
            <BillingInput/>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var OPTIONSFORM = [
  {labelOption: 'First Name', placeholder: 'First name'},
  {labelOption: 'Last Name', placeholder: 'Last name'},
  {labelOption: 'Website', placeholder: 'Store website'},
  {labelOption: 'Email', placeholder: 'Email contact'},
  {labelOption: 'Password', placeholder: ''},
  {labelOption: 'NIF', placeholder: ''},
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <BillingOption/>,
  document.getElementById('payment-system')
);
```

I thought about the interface this way:

BillingOption

- BillingLabel
- BillingInput

Each option is composed of a Label and an input box.

I want the interface to loop trough the list and build all the BillingOption's (in this case, 6 of them). I just have the First Name + Input for it rendered so far. How can I loop trough all to render all six?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`props`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html) to pass perform parent-child communication and transform data between components. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwt4pcae/3/):

```
var BillingLabel = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<b>{this.props.label}</b>);
  }
});

var BillingInput = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <form>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder={this.props.placeHolder}
            />
        </form>
    );
  }
});

var BillingOption = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    const form = this.props.options.map((option, i) => {
        return (
          <div key={i}>
              <BillingLabel label={option.labelOption}/>
              <BillingInput placeholder={option.placeholder}/>
          </div>
        )})
    return (
         <div>{form}</div>     
    );
  }
});

var OPTIONSFORM = [
  {labelOption: 'First Name', placeholder: 'First name'},
  {labelOption: 'Last Name', placeholder: 'Last name'},
  {labelOption: 'Website', placeholder: 'Store website'},
  {labelOption: 'Email', placeholder: 'Email contact'},
  {labelOption: 'Password', placeholder: ''},
  {labelOption: 'NIF', placeholder: ''},
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <BillingOption options={OPTIONSFORM}/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I only can't see the placeholder's, they don't render...Just a side note, I get this warning in my console log, using your code: warning.js:45 Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `BillingOption`.

Comment: Nevermind, I see that you updated the fiddle. it works now. perfect :) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I've committed a typo at first. Sorry. Glad to help you!

Comment: No problem :) I just still got that warning although... but thanks for the explanation and code. cheers